# ASP.NET MVC Razor. How to do not replace non us characters on fields IDs?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

If my POCO class does have an attribute like this:

```
public int Número {get; set;}
```

and them write it on my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Número)
```

it renders a input with underscores replacing the non standard us characters, like this:

```
<input name="Número" id="N_mero" type="text" />
```

Is possible to avoid it somehow? I would like to preserve the non standard characters on input ids in order to easily query with Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `EditorFor` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) that accepts a view data object to override the value used for the `id` attribute:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Número, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = nameof(Model.Número) } })
```

EDIT: It's not quite a global configuration solution where you can just flip a switch and have all your existing code work, but with an extension method it'll be easier going forward:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool overrideId = false)
{
    if (overrideId)
    {
        var propertyExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (propertyExpression != null)
        {
            return html.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = propertyExpression.Member.Name } });
        }
    }

    return EditorExtensions.EditorFor(html, expression);
}
```

You could even default the overrideId parameter to true to make all your existing usages work in place assuming you have the extension class in a namespace they're already using.

Comment: It works good, however I was looking for a global configuration, not doing this manually for each input.

Comment: I updated my answer to take your feedback into account.

Comment: By the way, I traced the framework code down to `InputExtensions.InputHelper`, which calls `TagBuilder.GenerateId` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.generateid.aspx)): "Valid characters consist of letters, numbers, and the hyphen ("-"), underscore ("_"), and colon (":") characters. All other characters are considered invalid. The ID attribute is sanitized by replacing any invalid characters in the name parameter with the character specified in the `IdAttributeDotReplacement` property."